# Присвоение функцией ключей словаря одной переменной, а значений - другой

Tags: python, python-3.x, словари

Данный код возвращает элемент словаря и все ключи, но мне нужно понять как возвращать ключ возвращенного элемента?

```
def getRandomWord(wordDict):  # получение секретного слова из списка
    wordKey = random.choice(list(wordDict.keys()))
    wordIndex = random.randint(0, len(wordDict[wordKey])-1)

    return wordDict[wordKey][wordIndex]

secretWord, secretSet = getRandomWord(words), str(words.keys())
```

Comment: Добавьте пример того что Вы передаете в функцию, и что хотите получить, будет более наглядно и понятно

Comment: "код возвращает элемент словаря и все ключи"... похоже на то, что в `getRandomWord` передается словарь со значениями-списками и возвращает он одно из этих значений, а не "элемент словаря и все ключи"... что у вас в `words` и что нужно вернуть?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понял:

```
def getRandomWord(wordDict):  # получение секретного слова из списка
    wordKey = random.choice(list(wordDict.keys()))
    wordIndex = random.randint(0, len(wordDict[wordKey])-1)

    return wordDict[wordKey][wordIndex], wordKey # добавил возвращение ключа

secretWord, secretKey = getRandomWord(words) # ключ берём из возврата функции, как и слово
```

Вы можете вернуть из функции всё, что хотите, в виде списка значений через запятую, и присвоить эти полученные из функции значения списку переменных. Фактически из функции при этом возвращается кортеж, который потом "распаковывается" в список переменных, но это уже детали.

Comment: Спасибо, вопрос убит :)